# Setting a port number inside my selinux module file

Tags: selinux

I'm trying to put together a small selinux module to further my understanding of selinux. I've defined a small daemon-like application type with its own port_type. The following code is a condensed version, replacing my own application type with httpd_t:

```
module mymodule 1.0;

require {
        type httpd_t;
        attribute port_type;
        class tcp_socket name_bind;
}

#============= my_port_t ==============

type my_port_t, port_type;
allow httpd_t my_port_t:tcp_socket name_bind;
```

I would now like to put the actual port number(s) for my_port_t into the module (or the generated package). The purpose is to avoid an explicit semanage call like this:

```
semanage port -a -t my_port_t -p tcp 9011
```

I know semanage makes the port number permanent, but I'd prefer to have a single file that takes care of everything. This way, distribution of the module to many systems would be much easier.

How can I do this? So far I haven't found a solution. Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 2):

`portcon` is the directive for this purpose, but according to the [Labeling a port in a loadable policy module](https://danwalsh.livejournal.com/10607.html) article, it's not possible outside the base module. The official [SELinux portcon docs](https://selinuxproject.org/page/NetworkStatements#portcon) say the same ("Module Policy: No").

However, this only applies to the traditional `.te` modules. [SELinux now also supports CIL](https://blog.siphos.be/2015/06/where-does-cil-play-in-the-selinux-system/) (Common Intermediate Language), where [it is supported](https://www.spinics.net/lists/selinux/msg21663.html). Supposedly, [you need to be on EL 7.3 or later, or Fedora 23 or later](https://www.spinics.net/lists/selinux/msg21664.html).

So in your case, the port definition itself would look like so:

```
; Declare a my_port_t type
(type my_port_t)
; Assign the type to the object_r role
(roletype object_r my_port_t)

; Assign the right set of attributes to the port
(typeattributeset defined_port_type my_port_t)
(typeattributeset port_type my_port_t)

; Declare tcp:9011 as my_port_t
(portcon tcp 9011 (system_u object_r my_port_t ((s0) (s0))))
```

This, however, only solves the problem with the port type definition. According to the [Fundamental SELinux Concepts](https://hub.packtpub.com/fundamental-selinux-concepts/), the remainder of the policy would be as simple as:

```
; Allow httpd_t to bind to my_port_t
(allow httpd_t my_port_t (tcp_socket (name_bind)))
```

---

If you want to just add additional ports to an existing port type, it's much simpler:

```
(portcon tcp 922 (system_u object_r ssh_port_t ((s0)(s0))))
```

You can save this file as say, `foobar-ssh.cil`, then you can install and verify the results like so:

```
# semodule -i foobar-ssh.cil
# semodule -l | grep foobar
foobar-ssh
# semanage port -l | grep ssh
ssh_port_t                     tcp      22, 922
```